# Python Key Error Missing Dict in LinkedIn API call - how to call default value instead?

Tags: python, api, dictionary, linkedin-api

I am calling the linkedin API and using json.loads to convert the JSON objects to Python lists and dicts.  Sometimes for certain LinkedIn profiles, they are missing a dict such as the end date for their university/education (bolded below).  What mechanism would I use to have it return a default value (i.e "N/A") instead of tripping up a "Key Error" for missing the dict?  I apologize for such a basic question, I'm just starting out with Python / Django. I really appreciate the help!

```
def home(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>"
    token = oauth.Token(request.user.get_profile().oauth_token,request.user.get_profile().oauth_secret)
    client = oauth.Client(consumer,token)
    headers = {'x-li-format':'json'}
    url_list = ["redacted-URL","redacted-URL", "redacted-URL"]
for x in url_list:
    url = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url="+x+":(id,first-name,last-name,headline,industry,three-current-positions,**educations:(end-date,**degree,field-of-study,school-name))" 
        resp, content = client.request(url, "GET", headers=headers)
        profile = json.loads(content)
    html += profile['firstName'] + " " + profile['lastName'] + ": " + profile['headline'] + " | " + profile['industry'] + " | " + profile['threeCurrentPositions']['values'][0]['company']['name']+ " | " + profile['threeCurrentPositions']['values'][0]['title']+ " | " + profile['educations']['values'][0]['fieldOfStudy']+ " | " + profile['educations']['values'][0]['degree']+ " | " + profile['educations']['values'][0]['schoolName']+ " | " **+str(profile['educations']['values'][0]['endDate']['year'])** + "<p/>"
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dict.get(key, default)` instead of `dict[key]` to specify a default value when doing a dictionary lookup.

Comment: thank you but I'm trying to figure out what the syntax would be if my dict[key] was str(profile['educations']['values'][0]['endDate']['year'])                                                                     I'm trying profile.get(str(profile['educations']['values'][0]['endDate']['year']), "NA") but it does not work.

Comment: That's because you're actually doing 5 chained dictionary lookups. It'd be something more like `profile.get('educations', {}).get('values', [{}])[0].get('endDate', {}).get('year', None)`

Comment: awesome - thanks so much!  where can i read more about the syntax of doing dictionary lookup?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dict.get` as given in above answer. Other way is check the key is exists or not like `if 'key' in dict: dict['key']`.